# If $(a_n)_n$ is convergent sequence than $\lim n(a_{n+1} -a_n)=?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a convergent sequence, how do I find
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n \Delta\left(a_{n+1}\right)
= \lim_{n \to \infty} n \left(a_{n+1} - a_n\right) ?
$$

I know that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1} - a_n = 0$$ but this is different.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1} - a_n$ or $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ or something else?

Comment: Use mathjax pls..

Comment: @shwetha i edited it

Comment: Why would that limit exist?

Comment: I mean limn→∞n(an+1−an)=??

Answer (score 3):

As already remarked by Clement C the limit can be $0$ (see $a_n=1$), or it may not exist (see $a_{n+1} = a_{n} + \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$).

I'll show that if the $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n $ exists, then the $\lim_{n\to \infty}n(a_{n+1} -a_n) $ is $0$.
Assume that it is positive (including $+\infty)$ then there exist $L>0$ and $N>0$ such that for all $n\geq N$,
$$a_{n+1} - a_n\geq \frac{L}{n}$$
which implies
$$a_{n}=a_N+\sum_{k=N}^{n-1}(a_{k+1} - a_k)\geq a_N+L\sum_{k=N}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\implies \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=+\infty$$
contradicting the fact that the sequence $(a_n)_n$ is convergent (to a finite limit).

Comment: What if it is given that $\Delta a_n$ is monotone and zero-convergent?

Comment: It depends on how fast it converges to zero. Compare $\Delta a_n=1/\sqrt{n}$ with $\Delta a_n=1/n^2$.

Comment: I have trouble on a specific case: if the sequence $\left{ a_n \right}$ is convex and bounded, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} na_n=0.$ By convex we mean $\Delta^2a_n \geq 0.$

Comment: @Emin Why don't you post a question?